# How to access key state in React Native?

Tags: arrays, react-native

How can I access a key from a state 

My state look like this :

```js
this.state = {        
   arrayRoom:[],
};
```

Then I have a function onPress on my component to set the state like this:

```js
onPress={() => this.handleRoomPicker({ "id":rooms.id, "name":rooms.name, "price": rooms.real_price})}
```

The function code like the following:

```js
 handleRoomPicker(data){
    this.setState({arrayRoom:this.state.arrayRoom + data}, function(){
        alert(this.state.arrayRoom.id)
    })
 }
```

The alert always return `undefined`.

I also tried to use :

```js
alert(this.state.arrayRoom.['id'])
```

Still return `undefined`. 

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Try to use push instead of +

Answer (score 0):

You are using alert to display the value from array but you need to convert them from javascript value to String value for displaying.

So, please try it:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.arrayRoom))
```

It will display value of array for you.

Comment: I used it already. What I really want is to get the value of key `id`. any idea ?

Comment: ok. let use lodash library to extract the array of id from your array. Then use alert to display

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is that your state object is an array but you are trying to access it like an object. It's also unclear if you want to replace the state with your new 'data' or you want to simply add to it so I'm going to try and do both.

In the case where you simply want to replace the state first change your state to

```
this.state = {
arrayRoom: { },
}
```

Then handleRoomPicker would look like

```
handleRoomPicker(data){
    this.setState( {arrayRoom: data ,  function(){
    alert(this.state.arrayRoom.id)
    }});
}
```

In the case when you want to add on to the arrayRoom object ( if there are other keys inside you don't want to lose )

```
this.state = {
  arrayRoom: { },
}

handleRoomPicker(data){
  this.setState({
      arrayRoom: {...this.state.arrayRoom, data},
      funtion() { alert(this.state.arrayRoom.id)}
  });
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your arrayRoom is array :

```
alert(this.state.arrayRoom['id'])
```

If is object

```
alert(this.state.arrayRoom.id)
```

Or

```
alert(this.state.arrayRoom['id'])
```

And in first render this.state.arrayRoom['id'] is undefined 
this.state.arrayRoom is empty